# Debugging Make / Concerto based Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

When I run `make`, it fails like this:

> | /bin/sh:
>   /home/ylee/tisdk-20180718/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc:
>   No such file or directory

When I look closely, the issue is obviously the path has extra directories that do not exist (arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/bin, which comes after /usr/bin).

It is a fairly large Makefile, but I am hoping that Concerto provides facilities to debug issues like this. Can someone please share a few tips?

Comment: Makefile debugging pretty much sucks. You can't even get a line number for the failure...

Comment: ?? Sure you do.  At least, with GNU make you'll get something like: `make: *** [Makefile:4: mytarget] Error 1`.  The `Makefile:4` here means file Makefile, line 4.